# Black screen on build after instantiation any GO in loaded scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, rendering, photon

I'm creating a multiplayer game using *Photon PUN2* on *Unity*. For now, I'm working on reconnection users in case restarting the game.

During the game, I change scenes with Photon (AutomaticallySyncScene = true and PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(...)) so when player is connecting, automatically loading current active scene. 
Everything works perfectly... in **unity editor**. But **on build** when connecting and loading scene screen is black. But Unity thinking all is ok because haven't thrown any errors : /

Additional "symptoms":

- reproduce ONLY on build version;
- black all screen but UI (draws and works correctly);
- screen become black only after instantiation of any GO;

I'm trying to change something the whole day... Please help

Unity version: 2019.3.10f1

Target platform: Windows 10

---

*My code. Hope it helps*

**Connecting to room and loading the preparing scene:**

```
public InputField nameField;

 void Start()
{
    RefreshUi(true);
    PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
    PhotonNetwork.GameVersion = "game_0.1b";
   PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
}

//on button click
public void JoinRoom()
{
    PhotonNetwork.NickName = nameField.text;
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom("Room_001");
}

public override void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("LobbyScene");
}
```

**Loading the next scene on my start game event:**

```
[PunRPC]
public void LoadUsers()
{
    ... // handeling data
    if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        return;
    PhotonNetwork.OpCleanRpcBuffer(photonView); 
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("GameRoom");
}
```

**Instantiating prefabs:**

```
protected override void Execute(List<GameEntity> entities)
{
    foreach (var e in entities)
    {
        var prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>(e.prefab.path);
        if (!prefab)
            continue;         
        var view = Object.Instantiate(prefab, _parent);
        e.ReplaceView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code. What is your build platform?

Comment: sorry. Already done

Comment: Hi, Thank you for choosing Photon! I don't think this is Photon related. Did you check [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/732218/black-screen-on-build-run.html), maybe it's a camera problem?